# Why is my GCM notification truncated? (Cordova PushPlugin)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm sending a very simply GCM push notification over HTTP. On my android it displays the first 32 characters, following by 3 dots. Messages from other apps appear just fine, all wrapped nicely.

The app side is an Ionic application (Cordova) using [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) as the client notification code.

example, the following code results in the message: `this is not such a long message to be trun...`

```
POST: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send    
{       
  "registration_ids":["secret"],
  "data": {
        "message" : "this is not such a long message to be truncated"
  }
}
```

Anyone knows this plugin and can help configuring it to display multiline notifications?

Comment: Change your notification type. If you can add your code where you are building the notification it would be easier for others to help you.

Comment: thx @Rohit5k2. what is a notification type? I don't seem to send it at all.

Comment: Maybe this is due to chunked data, your reception side may be tricky, you may want to show your code to debug this

Comment: I'm actually using the code from the questions above. simply sending the exact things via HTTP. that's it. not via native code.

Comment: @Tal: When you receive the notification on device you must be creating a notification. Please post that code.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 again, thx for your help, but I don't quite get what you're asking me to post. I am using an HTTP client to send a GCM HTTP notification, just as described here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging - nothing more to post than what I've already posted on my question. that's all the code I use.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 thx. your comment helped me realize it's the client side to blame. I changed the question to include that. I'm on Cordova using PhoneGap plugin as the client that displays the notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [ShibbyUK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494795/shibbyuk) answered, use BigTextStyle:

- There is a [pull request](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/267) for PushPlugin that does just this.
- Or you could modify the plugin yourself, by making these changes:

  ```
  if (extras.getString("bigview") != null) {
      boolean bigview = Boolean.parseBoolean(extras.getString("bigview"));
      if (bigview) {
          mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the style to "[BigTextStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html)" with setStyle when you build the notification e.g.

```
myBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText("this is not such a long message to be truncated"))
```

Comment: any way to do it via the HTTP request? I'm not using a library

Comment: @Tal you **cannot** fix this with a simple HTTP request. You will have to modify the plugin. Refer this [pull request](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/267) that does exactly the same

Comment: @Ajoy super! that fixes my issue. post it as an answer and I'll accept it for more people to find.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is only the [server side](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server) implementation of the GCM. For the client side (e.g. Android) it seems you used the sample Google provided on its docs.

If you want to handle your `message`, you have to modify (or implement) the [client side](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration) too. There you can choose how to display it on your devices in the Android (or iOS).